# How to use deck.gl to render a polygon layer that is using a different coordinate system than the standard LAT LONG?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, coordinates, polygon, deck.gl

### Background

I am using deck.gl's [PolygonLayer](https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/layers/polygon-layer) to render data that looks like this:

**data.json:**

```json
{
    "someKey": "someValue",
    "spatialReference": {
        "wkid": 23032,
    },
    "features": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "polygonName": "MY_POLYGON"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "rings": [
                    [
                        [421334, 7240529], ...
                    ],
                    [
                        [422656, 7250696], ...
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, the problem is that decg.gl uses a latitude-longitude coordinate-system, which is different from what this polygon is expressed in.

### Deck.GL documentation on rendering layers with different coordinate-systems

So, according to the [documentation](https://deck.gl/docs/developer-guide/coordinate-systems), deckGL renders each layer separately based on its coordinate system. Therefore, it was important to specify both `coordinateOrigin` and `coordinateSystem` props.

### Understanding the coordinate system in data.json

So, as far as I understood, the `spacialReference` value in data.json represents an [EPSG](https://epsg.io/?q=23032) code. Using [this website](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/utm-latitude-longitude-d_1370.html), I was able to find a value for the `coordinateOrigin` prop as `[63.510617, 9.210989, 0]`. As for the `coordinateSystem` prop, I used `COORDINATE_SYSTEM.METER_OFFSETS`. Here's the code:

**PolygonLayer.tsx:**

```ts
import React from "react";
import { COORDINATE_SYSTEM } from "@deck.gl/core/typed";
import { DeckLayer } from "@deck.gl/arcgis";
import { PolygonLayer } from "@deck.gl/layers/typed";
import MapView from "@arcgis/core/views/MapView";
import ArcGISMap from "@arcgis/core/Map";
import "@arcgis/core/assets/esri/themes/light/main.css";

export default function PolygonLayer({layerURL}) {
    const mapRef = React.useState(null)
    
    React.useEffect(() => {
        fetch(layerURL)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                const blobURL = new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)], {type: "application/json",});
                const url = URL.createObjectURL(blobURL); // this is needed for the layer
                
                const layer = new PolygonLayer({
                    id: data["features"][0]["attributes"]["polygonName"], // correctly defined
                    data: url,
                    filled: true,
                    getLineWidth: 3,
                    getLineColor: [255, 255, 255, 0],
                    getFillColor: [234, 243, 221, 0],
                    coordinateOrigin: [63.510617, 9.210989, 0], // based on the explanation above
                    coordinateSystem: COORDINATE_SYSTEM.METER_OFFSETS,
                    getPolygon: (d) => {
                        console.log(d); // doesn't log anything
                        return d.features[0].geometry.rings;
                    },
                });
                
                const deckLayer = new DeckLayer({
                    "deck.layers": [layer],
                });

                const arcgisMap = new ArcGISMap({
                    basemap: "topo-vector",
                    layers: [deckLayer]
                });

                new MapView({
                    container: mapRef?.current,
                    map: arcgisMap,
                    center: data["features"][0]["geometry"]["rings"][0][0], // correctly defined
                    zoom: 9
                });

            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }, [layerURL]);

    return <div ref={mapRef} style={{height: "90vh", width: "100%"}}></div>
}
```

### The issue with this code

The problem with this code is that it doesn't render the layer (or the base map) and there's nothing logged in the console for the value of `d`; as mentioned in the code above.

### Making sure the code works

Now, just a sanity check, I have used [this url](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/visgl/deck.gl-data/master/website/sf-zipcodes.json) which returns polygons data in the standard *LAT LONG* format, without using `coordinateOrigin` or `coordinateSystem` props as in [this example](https://codepen.io/pen?&editors=001) and **it worked**. So the code is ok rendering LAT LONG system, but breaks when using METERS_OFFSET as in the code provided.

### Therefore

Have I figured out the `coordinateOrigin` correctly? And how can I use this (or another type of) layer to render this data correctly? Any help is appreciated and apologies for the long question!

Comment: The [this example](https://codepen.io/pen?&editors=001) in the "Making sure the code works" section opens an empty codepen project.

Comment: @sidacu you're right! Apparently, the code gets lost when sharing the link. The example was given in deck.gl's PolygonLayer shown here: https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/layers/polygon-layer if you click on "edit on codepin" button on the top of the map.